Assert string as Guid with Fluent Assertions
Is there a way to assert if an incomming string is a Guid using Fluent Assertions?
Something like
var guid = "f0c70613-2667-4a9a-8c2c-69006e100d790";
guid.Should().BeOfType<Guid>();

It would involve casting the input string to a Guid type and that would be ok.
Currently using Guid.Parse(guid); and relying on the exception on incorrect input, but it's not very fluent-like.

Incoming where? In an API or serializer there's no need to validate if you make the field or parameter type Guid. The binder or serializer will detect any problems. This isn't exactly validation

If your UnitTest needs to test that a return value of type string has a content that can be parsed to a Guid I'd suggest to use Guid.TryParse and assert that to return true. The reason being that this would avoid the exception. But that's the only difference to your current approach.

"but it's not very fluent-like." - if you want that, you totally can put all that into an extension method.

Using Guid.TryParse in a Fluent Style:
var guid = "f0c70613-2667-4a9a-8c2c-69006e100d790";
guid.Should().Match(g => Guid.TryParse(g, out _));

Using Guid.Parse with Exception Assertion:
var guid = "f0c70613-2667-4a9a-8c2c-69006e100d790";
Action act = () => Guid.Parse(guid);
act.Should().NotThrow<FormatException>();

Custom Assertion Method for String to Guid:
public static class GuidAssertions
{
    public static void ShouldBeGuid(this string value)
    {
        value.Should().Match(g => Guid.TryParse(g, out _), "because the string should be a valid GUID.");
    }
}

Then you can use it like this:
var guid = "f0c70613-2667-4a9a-8c2c-69006e100d790";
guid.ShouldBeGuid();


Very clever usage of Match. Love the inline "reason" for failing the assertion.

If I got your requirement right, you could do something like this:
internal static class PickAGoodNameExtensions
{
    internal static void AssertGuidContent( this string source )
    {
        var canParse = Guid.TryParse(source, _);
        canParse.Should().BeTrue(); // Maybe add a custom Message?
    }
}

and use it like
var guid = "f0c70613-2667-4a9a-8c2c-69006e100d790";
guid.AssertGuidContent();

If you want to get really creative, you can even extend FluentAssertions as described here: Building your own extensions.
